# How: given m-inequlity constraints there are 2^m subsets of inequality constraints which can be converted to equality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, problem-solving

Consider a optimization problem: $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\beta_0+\beta_1x_i)^2$ subject to $\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i+1}\geq\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i}$ for $i=1,2$.

This can be solved by using ([ref:page (282)](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Linear_Models.html?id=Wv_UCgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)) the fact that: Given m-inequality constraints there could are $2^m$ possible subsets of inequality constraints which can be converted to equality constraints.

I am NOT getting how the above fact is coming? For example in the above given example which are $2^{m-1}$ (here $m$=2) subsets of inequality constraints that can be converted to equality constraints?

Comment: well i dont think there is anything in the world saying that a set of inequalities can be converted to equality constraints, unless that is actually part of the problem solution. Unless there are something else we are not seeing here. By the way page 282 is not in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

The objective function of your problem is non-linear. So I assume that you are solving your problem via Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) optimality conditions and you are looking for the active sets of constraints in order to satisfy the complementary conditions. This can be done checking exhaustively all the potential active subsets of the constraint set. If you have $m$ constraints, then you have $2^m$ subsets of constraints that can be active, that is satisfied as equalities. In your case $m=2$ and the active subsets you have to consider are: 
$$ I_1=\{1\}, I_2=\{2\}, I_3=\{1,2\}, I_4=\{\emptyset\}$$

When you solve the KKT system for $I_h, \ h=1\ldots m$,  you can set the Lagrangean multipliers $\lambda_i=0,\ \ \forall i \notin I_h$.